# Postgres-compatible Joomla-Components

Tags: php, postgresql, joomla

Since Joomla 2.5 supports PostgreSQL natively and we're very in favour of that one. As I am developing a component for our system, I am wondering what are the exact semantics to make it compatible?

For MySQL, I have my install script in `admin/sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql`. What would it be for PostgreSQL? And can I use the `#_` for the database prefix as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additional database support is meant to be as transparent as possible so you can keep the majority of your code the same.

If you've been using Joomla!'s JDatabase class you should be constructing your queries like this in your PHP:

```
    /* (example php may not actually work)
       Get the factory DB object */
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    // Get a new JDatabaseQuery object
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    // Build our query...
    $query->select('id');
    $query->from('#__mycomponents_table');
    $query->where('id=99');
    // Attach the query to the DB object
    $db->setQuery($query);
    // Run it and check the result...
    if (!$db->loadResult()){...}
```

As you've identified though things like install/uninstall SQL scripts will need to be database specific. This means a small update to your manifest XML as well... here's an example.

```
<install>
    <sql>
        <file charset="utf8" driver="mysql">sql/install.mysql.sql</file>
        <file charset="utf8" driver="postgresql">sql/install.postgresql.sql</file>
    </sql>
</install>
```

I would suggest looking through the `com_finder` code as it does have a specific example of install/uninstall SQL for Postgres.